# Batch script to check Office version in registry key's and create new Outlook profile

Tags: batch-file, outlook, profile, gpo

I have 100 PC's with different Office versions and I want to create a new Outlook profiles for all this PC's users with GPO. So I need a batch script which will check Office version in registry key's (maybe with reg query `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application\CurVer`) and then creates a new registry entry.
Example:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\NewProfile"
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook" /v DefaultProfile /t REG_SZ /d "NewProfile" /F
```

I tried this:

```
@Echo
reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application\CurVer" "(Default)" | Find "Word.Application.16" IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto first IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto second goto end
:second
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\NewProfile"
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook" /v DefaultProfile /t REG_SZ /d "NewProfile" /F
goto end
:first
goto end
:end
@exit
```

But It gives an error:

> ERROR: Invalid syntax. Type "REG QUERY /?" for usage.

Maybe someone knows where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
@Echo
reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application\CurVer" | (
    Find "Word.Application.16"  >nul 2>&1 ) && (
        goto :second
    ) || (
        goto :first
    )
:second
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\NewProfile"
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook" /v DefaultProfile /t REG_SZ /d "NewProfile" /F
goto :end
:first
goto end
:end
@exit
```